# Application blocks excel DDE communication

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, windows-messages, dde

I'm facing a strange issue here. I have a WPF application that does nothing with DDE messages. But any time I open an Excel spreadsheet that has DDE calculations referencing another application, Excel freezes completely and it only gets back again when the user closes my application.

Has anybody faced this issue before? I read that Google and Eclipse had this issue, but I can't find no place to check what they've done about it. My only clue is that it has something to do with Windows Messages (WM_DDE_INITIATE, etc.), but Spy++ gives me no relevant information.

Thanks in advance!

PS: This only occurs in Excel 2010. Excel 2013 is OK, but unfortunately my client can't update that Excel version

Comment: can you provide a bit more information for example how are you connecting to and or using the Excel file .. sound like a versioning issue.. can you post any code samples of where you are running into this issue...? what version of `Interop` are you using ..?

Comment: The big problem here is that I have no control of the other application. I'm assuming I'm causing this error because other applications (even one that is a DDE server) don't cause this behavior. It seems my application is not processing DDE messages correctly, but I cannot find where this is happening.

Comment: what about looking at the Event Viewer.. could it be that you're .DLL are not compatible ? what part of the code in the process did you add.. please clarify on that...